# How to find the maximum and minimum value of an array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi my array below like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0-10
    [1] => 10-20
)
```

then how to find the maximum and minimum value above array please tel me any one

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get maximum and minimum

```
 arr=Array(0=>"10-20",1=>"0-10");

Then you get the min and max:

$min = min($arr);
$max = max($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find max with max. Notice here that for min, "0-10" will be the result so this goes by the value not the index (in case the values are not in order).

```
$arr=Array(0=>"10-20",1=>"0-10");   
echo $arrmin=min($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

if i am understanding your problem..**try this codes**

```
<?php 
$arr = array('0-10','10-20');
print_r($arr);
$min = min($arr);
$max = max($arr);
echo $min . "<br>";
echo $max;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 

$data = array('0-10','10-20');
$min = min($data);
$max = max($data);
echo "<br> Min: ";
echo $min . "<br> Max: ";
echo $max;
```